# Time Out using SSL on Fedora 22

Tags: apache, ssl, vhosts

I've been receiving ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when I try to open a https page on my server since I upgrade my Fedora 14 to 22.
The server run on linode cloud, and was add an "A/AAAA Record" look like this:

```
HOSTNAME ssl_page.mysite.com
IP ADDRESS xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
TTL Default
```

My vhost.conf look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/mysite/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/mysite/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My ssl.conf looks like:

```
Listen 443 https
SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/ssl_page"
ServerName ssl_page.mysite.com:443
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite PROFILE=SYSTEM
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ssl_page.mysite.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ssl_page.mysite.com.key
<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

Neither "/var/log/http/ssl_error" or "/var/www/http/ssl_page/logs/error.log" have messages for this problem.

I even tried disable the firewalld, but it doesn't worked too.

Any one have a clue what are happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked, I just had to change my ssl.conf in this way:

```
Listen 443 https
SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ssl_page.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ssl_page
        Redirect permanent / https://ssl_page.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/ssl_page"
ServerName ssl_page.mysite.com:443
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite PROFILE=SYSTEM
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ssl_page.mysite.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ssl_page.mysite.com.key
<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

What was missing was the redirect directive.

Thanks anyway fellows!!!